# Managed App Field Visibility Control

Tags: managed-package, fields

We are working on an app that implements a schedulable batch class to import data for leads. 
We would like user-level control over who can see the custom fields with the data from the app, so the organization would have to buy the app and then a certain number of licenses for their users to split up. Is this possible through the licensing process or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a managed package, if you enforce user licensing (as opposed to Enterprise Licensing), only users with a licence can see any custom fields in the app, regardless of FLS rules applied in the target org. The customer then has to assign users to licenses via the Manage Licenses link next to package name in the Installed Package section. Bear in mind that the user login that the batch runs under will also need a license to the app - licensing applies to every user, including sys admin.